# Bash - run commands returned by grep

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm sorry, I really suck at bash...

I'm running a debian server for which I try to automate service restarts when they are updated. I use the tool `checkrestart` included in debian-goodies package.

Everything I managed to do up to now is to do:

```
checkrestart | grep "^service .* restart"
```

which outputs:

```
service apache2 restart
service bind9 restart
service ssh restart
```

How can I finish my little script so that the commands outputted are actually run?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `eval` on the output

Comment: like that? `checkrestart | grep "^service .* restart" | eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   checkrestart | grep "^service .* restart" | bash -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash). Upon initial investigation, I'm not sure if it's possible to pipe to it. However, you should still be able to use it like so:

```
eval $(checkrestart | grep "^service .* restart" | sed 's/$/;/')
```

`sed` is needed to add semicolons (`;`) at the end of each line so that `eval` will read them as separate commands.